# How to handle exceptions with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, exception

I've been using GAE for more than a year now, and one of the most difficult things for me to deal with is the fact that my otherwise well written code may occasionally raise an exception because of a GAE hiccup.

I already have a decent procedure for unhandled exceptions.  My custom request handler presents a nice error page and administrators get an email.  This, however, is a bad user experience.

What I want to do is to *handle* exceptions so I can immediately take the appropriate action and prevent some generic error page.

My questions are:

1. What exceptions should I catch?
2. Where should I catch them?

I realize that a full answer to this is not practical, but I'm looking for some best practices for the most common situations.

For exceptions that I should catch, I sometimes see exceptions that are not on the [official list](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/exceptions).  For example, I've received an UnknownError.

For where to catch exceptions, I wonder if I should catch them in each get/post method.  Something like this:

```
def get(self):
    try:
        # normal get processing
    except SomeException:
        # redirect to the same page to try again and fix any data if necessary
```

I'm surprised there is not more information out there about this as this is an important aspect of any GAE app.  There are some good articles [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors) and [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/03/Handling-downtime-The-capabilities-API-and-testing), but these don't answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

> What exceptions should I catch?

That depends upon what level of error catching you're going for. From my experience catching the errors in the official list and linked articles will get you a very high level of error catching. If you need to go above and beyond that putting in a generic except would be easier than trying to predict unknown errors.

> Where should I catch them?

The most likely place(s) for GAE errors is when interacting with the db, so setting some try-except blocks around there if you haven't will give you a good return on your effort for dealing with GAE-issue error handling.

Besides the advice of your linked articles you can also think about putting the failed operations into a task queue. Each task will automatically retry 5 times before failing which can give you some ability to ride out datastore switches or other service interruptions if you don't need immediate feedback from the operation.